# Postgres JSONB multiple attribute matches

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Say I have a JSONB object like this:

```
{"First":"Joe", "Last":"Smith", "Age": "29", "cat":"meow"}
```

I want to be able to find this JSONB object if I search just:

```
{"First":"Joe", "Age":"29"}
```

I tried this with a single attribute and it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name @> lower('{"First": "Joe"}')::jsonb
```

I tried this with two attributes and it did not work:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name @> lower('{"First": "Joe", "Last":"Smith"}')::jsonb
```

What am I missing? I figured based on the documentation this should work

Comment: What is not working?  Did you receive an error?  I tried your query in postgres 11 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I do not get the row as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `lower()`,  `@>` is case-sensitive.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name @> '{"First": "Joe", "Last":"Smith"}'::jsonb
```

If you want to make it a case-insensitive search, use `lower()` on the textual value of the JSON and put all attributes to match in lowercase (or may be apply `lower()` too )

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE lower(name::text)::jsonb 
        @> '{"first": "joe", "last":"smith"}'::jsonb
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=74c0e29fe8fb4ddbf8699a0c6e970281)